# How to create an AWS Lambda function from a Clojure project or a jar?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, clojure, aws-lambda, amazonica

The Amazonica test for the AWS Lambda API ([link](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica/blob/master/test/amazonica/test/lambda.clj)) shows a simple example of creating a Lambda function from a Javascript blob (`role` is an ARN string for a role that can create Lambdas):

```
(def handler "exports.helloWorld = function(event, context) {
                  console.log('value1 = ' + event.key1)
                  console.log('value2 = ' + event.key2)
                  console.log('value3 = ' + event.key3)
                  context.done(null, 'Hello World')
                }")

(create-function :role role :function handler)
```

Does anyone know if `create-function` can create a Lambda from a jar? Would simply passing a file stream or a binary string of the jar to `create-function` be a bad idea, even if it did work?

I suppose I could just use a bash script with the AWS CLI to create a Lambda from a jar, but first I wanted to check if there is a known straightforward method of doing this in Clojure.

Another option would be to upload the jar to an S3 bucket and then let a CloudFormation script deploy it, based on the example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#d0e62987). It seems a little silly though, to have an S3 bucket just to hold build artefacts, when Lambda will be storing them itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can do the upload via S3, I have an example of doing so here: https://github.com/langford/clj-aws-lambda-example

Very interested in this method as well. I agree the pit stop at S3 seems like it could be removed.

Comment: In case anything happens to that example, the relevant tool is `lein lambda` from https://github.com/mhjort/clj-lambda-utils. Looks like a good solution to me, I will try it next time I'm working with Lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that I can't thoroughly answer your question, but I've tried
   to deploy a hello-world clojure app, so to hopefully point you in the
   right direction:

- Login to your AWS Console
- Navigate to Lambda
- Open up the Hello World sample app
- From a dropdown menu select Java 8
- Upload your JAR directly
- Fill in the Classpath to your starter function (don't ask me why; I haven't gotten this right yet either)
- Click the Roles box and  follow the prompts to create the default reccomended roles config

If this isn't helpful please let me know!

Comment: The direct jar upload method eventually fails as your jar gets bigger and bigger. I don't remember the exact threshold, but it will be suddenly a bit of work as you figure out S3.